# How to display inline HTML images in a TextView in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Say I have some HTML like

This is text and this is an image http://www.example.com/image.jpg.

There's a resource called HtmlText that supports the styling that comes with the html but I can't find anything that supports displaying the images as well. How can I go about accomplishing this?

When I use HtmlText (from https://github.com/ireward/compose-html) the images are displayed as default icons. The github also mentions images aren't supported.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Aghajari/AnnotatedText/tree/main) is a library that converts `Spanned` to `AnnotatedString` which `Text` supports.

Answer (score 3):

First, we write the ImageGetter class in this way:

```
open class CoilImageGetter(
    private val textView: TextView,
    private val imageLoader: ImageLoader = Coil.imageLoader(textView.context),
    private val sourceModifier: ((source: String) -> String)? = null
) : Html.ImageGetter {

    override fun getDrawable(source: String): Drawable {
        val finalSource = sourceModifier?.invoke(source) ?: source

        val drawablePlaceholder = DrawablePlaceHolder()
        imageLoader.enqueue(ImageRequest.Builder(textView.context).data(finalSource).apply {
            target { drawable ->
                drawablePlaceholder.updateDrawable(drawable)
                // invalidating the drawable doesn't seem to be enough...
                textView.text = textView.text
            }
        }.build())
        // Since this loads async, we return a "blank" drawable, which we update
        // later
        return drawablePlaceholder
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private class DrawablePlaceHolder : BitmapDrawable() {

        private var drawable: Drawable? = null

        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            drawable?.draw(canvas)
        }

        fun updateDrawable(drawable: Drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable
            val width = drawable.intrinsicWidth
            val height = drawable.intrinsicHeight
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
            setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
@Composable
fun HtmlText(html: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context -> TextView(context) },
        update = {
            it.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT,
                CoilImageGetter(it),
                null
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Image loading works but if the image is at the bottom of a scrollable view it gets cut off

Answer (score -3):

To display an image from a url use [coil library](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/).

Add the dependency to the project with

```kt
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
```

Then use `AsynImage` to display the image

```kt
AsyncImage(
    model = "https://example.com/image.jpg",
    contentDescription = "Example image"
)
```